# Dynamically change the number of 'defer' calls in queue.js

Tags: javascript, queue.js

My webpage lets the user plot multiple timeseries on a chart and I am using queue.js to go and asynchronously get this data, like so:

```
queue()
.defer(d3.json, "api/TransactionCost/?marketCode=" + marketCode1)
.defer(d3.json, "api/TransactionCost/?marketCode=" + marketCode2)
.defer(d3.json, "api/TransactionCost/?marketCode=" + marketCode3)
.await(onDataLoaded);

function onDataLoaded(error, json1, json2, json3) {
  // plot the 3 timeseries
}
```

I want the user to be able to request extra lines, if they wish, which will mean that I need to do extra 'defer' calls. **I'd like to know how to dynamically append  extra 'defer' calls** (if it's possible) and also how to create the 'onDataLoaded' function so that it can handle a variable amount of parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'd like to know how to dynamically append extra 'defer' calls (if it's possible)

Use a variable for the queue, and dynamically append `defer` calls to it:

```
var q = queue();
for (/* each file */)
    q = q.defer(d3.json, filename);
q.await(onDataLoaded);
```

> how to create the 'onDataLoaded' function so that it can handle a variable amount of parameters.

You can use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to access a variadic amount of parameters. In your case, it would look like

```
function onDataLoaded(error) {
    if (!error) {
        // Either simply loop them:
        for (var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++)
            … arguments[i] …
        // or slice them into an array:
        var jsons = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        …
    } else { … }
}
```

Comment: @Bergi: a closing `}` is missing in the first code sample.

Comment: @Bergi: o.o , from what I see ( `for (/* each file */)
    q = q.defer(d3.json, filename);
q.await(onDataLoaded);` ) you deleted the opening `{` of the for loop instead of restoring the closing `}`.