# d3.js: Nesting data - key returns undefined for all data

Tags: d3.js

I'm messing around with the [last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api). I'm pulling a [user's top artists data](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getTopArtists), which returns a JSON like this:

```
{   "artist": [
      {
        "name": "Kanye West",
        "playcount": "282",
        "mbid": "164f0d73-1234-4e2c-8743-d77bf2191051",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Kanye+West",
        "streamable": "0",
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Childish Gambino",
        "playcount": "148",
        "mbid": "7fb57fba-a6ef-44c2-abab-2fa3bdee607e",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Childish+Gambino",
        "streamable": "0",
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "2"
        }
      },
```

And so on. After a bit of fiddling, I pull a second JSON, for [an artist's popular tags](http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getTopTags) (e.g. rock, pop, hip hop), loop through each artist, and push their most popular tag to the original dataset. So now my JSON looks like:

```
{   "artist": [
      {
        "name": "Kanye West",
        "playcount": "282",
        "mbid": "164f0d73-1234-4e2c-8743-d77bf2191051",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Kanye+West",
        "streamable": "0",
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "1"
        },
        "tag": "hip hop",
      },
      {
        "name": "Childish Gambino",
        "playcount": "148",
        "mbid": "7fb57fba-a6ef-44c2-abab-2fa3bdee607e",
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Childish+Gambino",
        "streamable": "0",
        "@attr": {
          "rank": "2"
        },
        "tag": "hip hop",
      },
```

The next thing I want to do is use `d3.nest` to roll up my data using each tag (genre) as the key. I'm following this [tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/). My ultimate goal is to make a [sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423), with genre on the inner ring (e.g. how much hip hop, indie, pop do you listen to?) and - maybe on a click - how much of each artist you listen to (e.g. Kanye West vs. Childish Gambino).

The main problem is here:

```
        var dataset = d3.nest()
                        .key(function(d) { 
                            return d.tag; 
                        })
                        .entries(topArtists);
```

The `key` is returning `undefined` for all data points. When I try other possible keys (`d.name`, `d.streamable`), they work fine. My data gets rolled up as desired. So it's something to do with `tag` - which is the object I pushed to the `topArtists` dataset. I'm not sure what's going on. Here's how I looped through and combined the artist info with the tag info:

```
    //Merge
    topArtists.forEach(function(d) {

        //loop through each of the top 10 artists selected
        //pull their mbid (musicbrainz id) and plug it into the var for tags            
        tags = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptags&mbid='+ d.mbid + '&api_key=[my api key]&format=json';

            //pull that JSON
            d3.json(tags, function(error, tag) {

                if (error) { return console.log(error); };

                //capture only the most commonly used tag (artistTag)
                //and also clean it up a bit
                artistTag = tag.toptags.tag[0].name.toLowerCase().split('-').join(' ');

                //push that string value to the original JSON
                d["tag"] = artistTag;


            }); // close tags JSON call 
        }); //close topArtists loop
```

After closing these loops, if I `console.log(topArtists)`, it all looks fine - the tags have been added. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anarres/sw2qwfkb/1/).

Comment: The problem is that `d3.json` is asynchronous. It runs after the `forEach` loop finishes. You may want to consider [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) for this.

Comment: Thanks, Lars. I was thinking it might be asynchronous - but when I run `console.log(topArtists)` *outside* of both the `forEach` loop and the second JSON call, it looks fine - all the `tags` are appended. If, on the very next line, I try `d3.nest` - they turn up as undefined. Indeed, even if I do `d3.nest().key(function(d) { console.log(topArtists); })`, the tags are showing up. They're just, for some reason, not being rolled up.

Comment: So `console.log()` prints an object that's not shown completely right? As in, you click on it to expand the attributes etc. The time when you click is actually when it's evaluated. That is, at the time you print the expression, it's not there, but when you click on it, it is. You can see this by printing the same expression twice, before and after putting data into it. When you inspect those objects on the console, they will be the same even though they're clearly different when you print them.

Comment: Ooh, I see. Yeah, I just tried that out - `tags` were showing up in my `console.logs` *above* the `forEach` loop, as well as after it. `queue.js` it is, I guess. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Lars's suggestion yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815018/d3-js-nesting-data-key-returns-undefined-for-all-data?noredirect=1#comment42203754_26815018), I managed to get this working, using the [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) library by Mike Bostock. In case anyone else runs into this problem, here are the steps I followed:

First, I called `queue.js` in my `<head>`, right after the `d3.js` call:

```
            <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
```

The main thing I wanted to do was:

1. User enters a last.fm username.
2. The `script` pulls up a JSON of the [user's top 10 (or 20, or whatever) artists](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getTopArtists).
3. Pull the "musicbrainz id" (a unique numerical identifier) for each artist, and do a series of 10 (or 20, or whatever) additional `d3.json` calls to get the [artist's top tags](http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getTopTags).
4. Merge the most commonly used `tag` into the original top artists JSON, for each artist. (Artists can have many user-written `tags`, so I only pull the most commonly-used one.)
5. Next - the visualization.

In practice, this meant doing a `d3.json` call first of the top artists (`topArtists`), and, within that, a `queue.js` call - where each `queue.defer()` is a function of what was in the `topArtists` JSON. Following that, I can loop through, add the `tag` to each `topArtists` item, and then use `d3.nest` to arrange my data around the `tags` as `keys`.

Here's what it all looks like:

First, the outer JSON call for `topArtists`. I do this to set `topArtists` to a JSON, otherwise, if I try to nest it within `queue.js`, I end up with infinite loops.

```
d3.json(top, function(error, json) {

    if(error) { return console.log(error); } 

    topArtists = json.topartists.artist;
```

Next, following [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687230/dynamically-change-the-number-of-defer-calls-in-queue-js), I set up a `queue()` that (1) calls the same `topArtists` JSON from the last.fm API again (this is the `topArtists` I'll use going forward to build my ultimate dataset), and then (2) dynamically calls the `tags` APIs for each artist.

```
    var q = queue()
        .defer(d3.json, top);

    topArtists.forEach(function(d) { 

            tags = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettoptags&mbid='+ d.mbid + '&api_key=[my api key]&format=json'

            q.defer(d3.json, tags);

            });
```

After all these JSONs have been loaded, I loop through and (after checking that the names match), append each artist's tag to the `topArtists` data, renamed `dataset`.

```
    q.awaitAll(function() {         


            dataset = arguments[1][0].topartists.artist

            for (var i = 1; i < arguments[1].length ; i++) {

                var j = i - 1;

                var artistName = arguments[1][0].topartists.artist[j].name;
                var artistTagName = arguments[1][i].toptags['@attr'].artist;

                if ( artistName == artistTagName ) {

                    artistTag = arguments[1][i].toptags.tag[0].name.toLowerCase().split('-').join(' ');

                    dataset[j]["tag"] = artistTag;

                };

            }; //close for loop
```

Without closing out `queue.awaitAll()`, I can now use `d3.nest` to roll up my data. `dataset` is now ready to be used in a visualization; which will also be called within `.awaitAll()`.

```
            dataset = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) {
                    return d.tag; 
                })
                .entries(dataset);

            console.log(dataset);
```